# Python- Compiled firmware to bits back to compiled firmware

Tags: python, byte, bit, compiled

I need to transfer compiled code into raw bits, then back into compiled
code, for a project. I have gotten my .uf2 file into Python, and I have gotten it to show as bytes and as encoded into ANSI text, but I haven't figured out how to turn it into bits. I can add that output here, but it is incredibly long so for readability I left it out. By extension, I also haven't figured out how to turn it back into a functioning .uf2 file. Does anyone have any ideas? Is it even possible to take compiled code and turn it bits without destroying it?

Edit:
Here is my code so far. I need to be able to access the bits, not the bytes. Data is encoded in ANSI.

```
fpath= input("File path: ")

f = open(fpath,'rb')
hexdec = f.read()
print(hexdec)
decode = hexdec.decode('ansi')
print(decode)
```

Comment: It's totally unclear what the full context is. What  is the difference between "raw bits" and "binary"? Binary is in the end just raw bits. Please show the code you have and describe in the code what is missing/incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo

Comment: When you talk about turning it into bits, what do you mean ? hexdec = f.read() is already binary data

Comment: I need to read the code as individual bits (100110), the output as I understand it is in bytes

Comment: When you say read the code in bits, do you mean printing 1's and 0's ?

Comment: Yes, printing as bits. If it's easier, I can work with hexadecimal as well. On the other end, I need to be able to turn those printed out bits/hexadecimals back into the original .UF2 file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a hex string to a byte array using the `fromhex()` method of bytearray

Then it's a simple matter of writing back the binary file

```
binary_data = bytearray.fromhex(hex_string)
newfile = open(path, 'wb')
newFile.write(binary_data)
newFile.close()
```